# How to find Average of student's grades using the last grade he got at a subject in case he got more

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one for `Grades` and one for `Students`. The `Grades` table has a column `Student` which is a foreign key referencing to `Student.Id`.

Students have multiple grades at different subjects and some of the students have more than one grade at a subject. If a student has more than one grade at a subject, how can I do the general average of those grades using only the last grade he got at each subject, rather than all grades?

For example, if a student has `Maths=3,History=5,Physics=4,History=7` I want to do the average using only Maths(3),Physics(4) and the last History(7), without the History(5).

[image: Check out this image]

As you can see in that image, i have a Students table with Name, Group, Location and a Grades table that have those grades. I want to do the average of those grades but in case there are more than 1 grad at the same subject the last grade at that subject should be used. In this case the avg should be AVG of French(9) + Maths(10) + the last grade taken at physics which is 5.

I'm sorry i just cant figure out what to do in this case. I am new to using relational databases, foreign keys etc.

So far i thought about using de Id to differentiate the grades. So for Physics 4 which is the first grade of that student it has the id of 1 and the Physics 5 which is the last grade he got at Physics it has the id of 7. So to get the last grade of that subject it should take the one with the higher id number but i can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you use a [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) first, you can then easily apply the `AVG`.

Comment: _last grade_? Can you show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh  https://imgur.com/a/WBsVUaq  as you can see in that image i have a Students table with Name, Group, Location and a Grades table that have those grades. I want to do the average of those grades but in case there are more than 1 grad at the same subject the last grade at that subject should be used. In this case the avg should be AVG of French(9) + Maths(10) + the last grade taken at physics which is 5.

Comment: Why not create markdown tables in your question with some testdata instead of linking an image (which is step worse than including image of the data in the question). A good question shouldn't make it hard to find the data and names of the tables to use

Comment: You have to be able to define "last" using something in the data, and not just insertion order  or the order rows are stored on disk.

Comment: Also, images of technical information like sample data are **not generally helpful.** We need _formatted text._ Especially, we want to see **actual column definitions** (which will hopefully include a date column with the Grades).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn hi, the grades table does not contain a column for date.

Comment: @RandyOrton Then you have a problem. SQL databases explicitly disclaim any responsibility to preserve any natural row ordering. There are a number of things that can cause them to reshuffle rows on disk or return them in a different order than you expect. You **MUST** be able to define "last grade" in terms of data actually in the table, or you will not _not be able to write this query_. Even a sequential ID value in the grades table would be enough, but you need _something_. Also pay attention to the note at the end of my answer about unreasonable schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a reasonable schema definition (*please share the actual schema definition with column names and types in the question*, and **do not use an image to do it**), you want something like this:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name, s.[Group], s.Location, AVG(g.Grade)
FROM 
( 
    SELECT Student, Subject, Grade
        ,row_number() over (partition by student, subject order by [ID] desc) rn
    FROM Grades
) g
INNER JOIN Students s ON s.Id = g.Student
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY s.ID, s.Name, s.[Group], s.Location
```

This uses a **windowing function** to partition and then number rows per student/subject based on the date, so you can then limit to only the first row within each partition and take the average from there. It should tend to perform better than solution which need to JOIN to a projection selecting by the `MAX(date)`.

Note I said "reasonable schema" at the beginning of the answer. There is a concern based on the image (which again: it gets squished in the view and is nearly unreadable — *don't post data that way!*) that multiple grades for a subject are stored in the same column as comma-separated data. This is what we call an **unreasonable** schema. Storing comma-separated data in a single column is considered a *BROKEN* schema design: something that needs to be fixed.

Another important thing to understand is the use of the `Date` column, which was not shown in the question. **SQL databases explicitly disclaim any responsibility for preserving any kind of natural order for your records**. There is *no such thing* as insert order, table order, or disk order, and there are a number of things that can cause a database to reshuffle records on disk or return rows in a different order, *even for consecutive runs of the same query.*

Therefore, you **MUST** have a way to define "last grade" in terms of *actual data in the rows*. Even a sequentially assigned ID would be enough, but we need **something**. Otherwise, *you will not be able to write this query!* What is it that makes `History(7)` be last rather than `History(5)`?

Comment: I thought i could differentiate them by id. Like the History(5) which is the last grade he got has the id of 4 and History(7) has the id of 2 for example. In this case the one with the highest id should be the last i think

Comment: Okay, that will work. **Edit the question** to include that information in your sample data. Look here to learn how to do it in way that will actually be readable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Answer (score 0):

use the MAX() function to get the most recent grade for each subject. You can then calculate the average of these grades using the AVG() function.

Here is an example:

```
    SELECT Students.Name, AVG(Grades.Grade)
FROM Students
JOIN (
    SELECT Student, Subject, MAX(Date) AS LatestDate
    FROM Grades
    GROUP BY Student, Subject
) AS LatestGrades ON Students.Id = LatestGrades.Student
JOIN Grades ON LatestGrades.Student = Grades.Student
    AND LatestGrades.Subject = Grades.Subject
    AND LatestGrades.LatestDate = Grades.Date
GROUP BY Students.Name
```

Comment: This is almost what i need, I updated the question adding more details about the problem. Please take a look again

Comment: I updated my answer and hopefully this what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a new table first that has the LatestGrades and then create the JOIN. Looks like You don’t even need the subj column in the final output, just an avg score across all subjects for every student.

```
WITH
Newtable AS 
(SELECT id, subject,grade, MAX(date) as LatestDate
FROM Grades
GROUP BY student, subject)
SELECT Students.id, students.name, AVG (newtable.grade) AS Avggrade
FROM (Newtable FULLJOIN Grades
ON Newtable.id=Grades.id) 
FULL JOIN Students ON students.id=grades.id
```